# Difficulties with dependencies in maven

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

i'm really new to creating projects in java with maven and so i've stumbled on quite a error for something really basic. I've created a maven project with the following pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.kthmaven</groupId>
    <artifactId>KTHMaven</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>edu.princeton.cs.introcs</groupId>
         <artifactId>algs4-package</artifactId>
         <version>1.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>edu.princeton.cs.introcs</groupId>
         <artifactId>stdlib-package</artifactId>
         <version>1.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>junit</groupId>
         <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
         <version>4.10</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   <repositories>
      <repository>
         <id>sics-release</id>
         <name>SICS Release Repository</name>
         <url>http://kompics.sics.se/maven/repository</url>
      </repository>
   </repositories>
</project>
```

Now when I try to compile the following code

```
package com.mycompany.kthmaven; 
public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
     long counter = 0;
     for (int i=0; i<1000000; i++) {
     counter += i;
     }
     StdOut.println("Körtiden var: " + stopwatch.elapsedTime());
    }

}
```

I get a error telling me it doesnt recognize the symbols Stopwatch and StdOut which do exist in the dependencies I assigned for the project. Maven also succeeds in downloading the jars so im not sure where the problem is.

Heres a picture how the project looks like in netbeans (sorry cant upload images yet)

http://i.gyazo.com/d9aa109c9bc34238f3548f7548dfb234.png

Comment: silly question: did you add the import xxx..yyyy.Stopwatch to your java class? I think you probably omitted it to simplify but just in case.

Comment: Oh...right, I actually didnt include that because I somehow assumed maven would take care of that, thanks!

Comment: Either you or @JoséAlejandro should add that as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Checked your pom.xml with your code in NetBeans and it works fine - jars were downloaded, code was built successfully and was run as well with no exception. Check if you can build it outside of your IDE - from command line write mvn clean install (from pom location) if it will finish successfully (as it generally should) go back to your IDE and check in console output after building project if mvn clean install is actually executed. If not check your configurations and set it correctly. After this action everything should be ok - your pom and code is ok.

[EDIT] Of course I assumed that you added appropriate imports (fix imports). If not then it is a problem as José Alejandro pointed out.